# Docker hostname and other container resolution with driver NAT

Tags: docker, docker-network

I'm becoming mad with Docker under Windows 2019 server. in my docker, for desktop, I've bridge network and it's really simple either to resolve host.docker.internal or another container name when it's passed via `--name h1` for example.

Under Docker in Windows 2019 server, I've not got the bridge driver (when I run `docker network create --driver=bridge net3` I got `Error response from daemon: could not find plugin bridge in v1 plugin registry: plugin not found`)

So as far I've read the nat driver should be equal, but when I try to resolve the host container I got
`server can't find host.docker.internal: SERVFAIL` and the same happens when I try to resolve a container

```
** server can't find n6.mshome.net: SERVFAIL

** server can't find n6.mshome.net: SERVFAIL

/ # nslookup n6.net1
Server:         192.168.240.1
Address:        192.168.240.1:53

** server can't find n6.net1: SERVFAIL

** server can't find n6.net1: SERVFAIL

/ # nslookup n6.net1.local
Server:         192.168.240.1
Address:        192.168.240.1:53

** server can't find n6.net1.local: SERVFAIL

** server can't find n6.net1.local: SERVFAIL

/ # nslookup n6.net1.internal
Server:         192.168.240.1
Address:        192.168.240.1:53

** server can't find n6.net1.internal: SERVFAIL

** server can't find n6.net1.internal: SERVFAIL
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: What is your DNS server setup? What is the basic image of your container?

Comment: I use two type of images : alpine and node .... the DNS setup is the default one (nothing has been touched), why?